# Argument for Vegetarianism

Tags: ethics, schopenhauer

I was wondering, what are some philosophical arguments for vegetarianism that are not hedonistic. I understand the hedonist's argument for vegetarianism, however I would like to understand a different one. For example, how would Schopenhauer argue vegetarianism. I would like as many diverse arguments as possible.

Comment: Is there any chance you might be able to specify a little more narrowly what you're looking for here?

Comment: This question shows some prior research. It may be "too broad" http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions but an answer could have broad-but-specific arguments (of different type). "List questions are generally discouraged", but it seems Mr. Smith honestly is seeking a non-opinion based answer anyway. [Keelan, I'm quoting you.]

Comment: @AdamUraynar not sure why, though. You seem to argue against the closure of this question. But it is not closed and never has been.

Comment: [A Utilitarian Argument For Vegetarianism](http://digitalcommons.calpoly.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1069&context=bts)

Answer (score 1):

Schopenhauer's *On the Basis of Morality* ~ morality stems from sentient compassion

- It follows that by not exercising compassion towards all sentient creatures, one is being immoral by definition.

Preference utilitarianism ~ the least amount of suffering for sentient beings

- Unnecessary non-human suffering is still suffering (granted this would not be the case for humanely slaughtered animals)

Buddhist philosophy ~ compassion (in a nutshell) towards all beings

- Although, the brass tacks of vegetarianism in Buddhism is the first precept to abstain from killing (of [this kind](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/5950/8475)). It can get complicated between different Buddhist schools, so take these brief words with a grain of salt, and know it is only meant generally.

Lastly, there is a "food-ethics" tag on Quora. This question website is better overall for exploring questions informally. That being mentioned, here are few sources for a more thorough understanding:

- [Compassion in Schopenhauer and Śāntideva](http://blogs.dickinson.edu/buddhistethics/files/2014/12/Hutton-Schopenhauer.pdf#page=3)
- [Schopenhauer's shared knowledge continuum (and beyond)](http://indiana.edu/~relstud/assets/docs/Shapshay_Schopenhauer.pdf#page=4)
- [How Schopenhauer’s ethics of compassion can contribute to today’s ethical debate](https://ddd.uab.cat/pub/enrahonar/enrahonar_a2015v55/enrahonar_a2015v55p41.pdf)